# JDBC connection timed out on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, jdbc, db2, db2-luw

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Start");
    try {
        Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("user", "xxx");
        properties.put("password", "xxx");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50000/xxxxxx", properties);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT DESC_UFF FROM UFFICIO";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("DESC_UFF"));
        }
        conn.close();
        System.out.println("Stop");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I use a jar file and it works fine on Windows XP and Windows 7, on a different PC, but not on Windows 10.

On Windows 10 I have this error:

```
Start
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][2043][11550][4.14.146] Eccezione java.net.ConnectException: errore durante l'apertura del socket sul server /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx sulla porta 50.000 con il messaggio Connection timed out: connect. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:320)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:338)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.wb.a(wb.java:434)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.wb.<init>(wb.java:93)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.b(a.java:354)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.newAgent_(b.java:2030)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.initConnection(Connection.java:732)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:680)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:334)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:233)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:199)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:475)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:116)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at main.TestDb2.main(TestDb2.java:20)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.w.run(w.java:49)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.wb.a(wb.java:420)
    ... 13 more
```

The version of DB2 database is 9.7 and Windows firewall is disabled.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I saw a post saying a similar question. Are you using Windows 10 + Java 8? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273994/socket-connect-timeout-ceiling

Comment: Try to do a telnet;  telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 50000, this works?

Comment: I use on the pc with windows 10 java 8, on the other pc java 6 and 7. I tryed telnet, on xp i receved a black screen and then nothing else, on 10 connection refused